# SQL get MAX datetime in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I am running a query against a table and doing a left join to try and get the record from the left table with the most recent date but it's not picking up the other values relevant to the datetime column (user and notes)

```
SELECT
    i.customer_sequence,
    i.due_date,
    
    MAX(cn.datetime) as notes_datetime,
    cn.user as notes_user,
    cn.notes as notes_notes
FROM
    billing_invoices i
LEFT JOIN customer_notes cn
    ON i.customer_sequence = cn.customer_seq
WHERE
    cn.type = 'Accounts' AND
    i.customer_sequence <> '0' AND
    i.status = 'Unpaid' AND
    i.directdebit <> 'Y'
GROUP BY
    i.customer_sequence
ORDER BY
    i.due_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation is not the solution here. You want the entire row from the joined table, so this suggest filtering instead. If you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        i.customer_sequence,
        i.due_date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.customer_sequence ORDER BY cn.datetime DESC) rn,
        cn.datetime as notes_datetime,
        cn.user as notes_user,
        cn.notes as notes_notes
    FROM billing_invoices i
    LEFT JOIN customer_notes cn
        ON  i.customer_sequence = cn.customer_seq
        AND cn.type = 'Accounts'
    WHERE
        i.customer_sequence <> '0' AND
        i.status = 'Unpaid' AND
        i.directdebit <> 'Y'
) t
ORDER BY i.due_date DESC
```

Note that I moved the condition on the `left join`ed table from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join (otherwise, this acts like an `inner join`).

---

In earlier versions, one option is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    i.customer_sequence,
    i.due_date,
    cn.datetime as notes_datetime,
    cn.user as notes_user,
    cn.notes as notes_notes
FROM billing_invoices i
LEFT JOIN customer_notes cn
    ON  i.customer_sequence = cn.customer_seq
    AND cn.type = 'Accounts'
    AND cn.datetime = (
        SELECT MAX(cn1.datetime)
        FROM customer_notes cn1
        WHERE i.customer_sequence = cn1.customer_seq AND cn1.type = 'Accounts'
    )
WHERE
    i.customer_sequence <> '0' AND
    i.status = 'Unpaid' AND
    i.directdebit <> 'Y'
```

Comment: that returns an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY i.customer_sequence ORDER BY cn.datetime DESC) rn,
        cn.dat' at line 6`

Comment: just tried the updated, and that gives a bigger error starting with `20 errors were found during analysis.`

Comment: @charlie: I suppose your version of MariaDB does not support window functions (they were added in 10.3). I updated my answer with a solution without window functions.

Comment: ok that works although seems to have slowed the query down a fair bit. is there a way to speed it up or would it be faster to loop the `billing_invoices` table with a query in each loop to `customer_notes`?

Comment: @charlie: you could try and take advantage of an index on `customer_notes(customer_seq, type, datetime)`. You could also upgrade to a recent version of MariaDB and use the window function solution.